# Does "Shield Specialization" apply to an unwielded "Winged Shield"?

Tags: dnd-4e

Will I get the feat bonus if I am using both hands to wield a two-handed weapon and having the Winged Shield float near me?

The feat:

> **Shield Specialization**
>
> **Benefit:** You gain a +1 feat bonus
> to AC and Reflex when using a shield with which you are proficient.

And the item:

> **Winged Shield**
>
> **Property:** You do not need to use
> your shield hand to gain the shield’s bonus to AC and Reflex; it
> floats about within your reach as if you wielded it. You can use your
> shield hand to hold another item, climb, wield a weapon, make attacks
> and so on. If you have a free hand, you may count as wielding a shield
> as a free action. Attempts to take away the shield are resolved as if
> you wielded it normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The key part is in the description of the shield:

> **Property:** You do not need to use
>   your shield hand to gain the shield’s bonus to AC and Reflex; it
>   floats about within your reach ***as if you wielded it***.

So the floating counts as wielding the shield, so the feat bonuses will apply also.

Comment: But it also says "If you have a free hand, you may count as wielding a shield as a free action." and in this case, the character has no free hand.

Comment: Then it's not a free action to wield. Has no bearing on the bonuses. The shield counts as being wielded. That's all that is necessary for the feat bonuses.

Comment: It sounds contradictory to me; they first say "as if you wielded it", implying that you are always wielding it, but then they state "you can count as wielding it as a free action", implying that you aren't always wielding it.

Comment: @firedraco - You aren't always wielding a shield even if it isn't floating around you. If you have it stowed, wielding it is a free action. Then the bonuses kick in again.